# Некорректное отображение текста RichTextBox в ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Имеется следующее окно WPF в .Net Framework 4.0:

```
<Window x:Class="EasyDiagnost.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
<Grid>
    <ListBox Margin="0" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
        <RichTextBox>
            <FlowDocument>
                <Paragraph>
                    <Run Text="One"/>
                </Paragraph>
            </FlowDocument>
        </RichTextBox>
        <RichTextBox>
            <FlowDocument>
                <Paragraph>
                    <Run Text="Two"/>
                </Paragraph>
            </FlowDocument>
        </RichTextBox>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

Текст в RichTextBox отображается ни слева направо, а сверху вниз. Как это исправить? Уже всю голову сломал!

[image]

Comment: Быть может, вместо VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" у ListBox нужно поставить Word Wrapping в true у RichTextBox'ов

Comment: у RichTextBox нет параметра Word Wrapping и подобного ему. Это же RichTextBox, а не TextBox. По крайней мере я не нашел такого

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Возможно, это баг у `RichTextBox`.

У меня работает так:

```
<Grid>
    <ListView x:Name="LV">
        <RichTextBox Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=LV}">
            <FlowDocument>
                <Paragraph>One</Paragraph>
            </FlowDocument>
        </RichTextBox>
        <RichTextBox Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=LV}">
            <FlowDocument>
                <Paragraph>
                    <Run Text="Two"/>
                </Paragraph>
            </FlowDocument>
        </RichTextBox>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Еще раз большое спасибо. Сделал то же самое, но в коде. Думал голова кипит, а оно оказывается баг.

Comment: А вообще существует жилетка, куда можно наплакать все баги для их устранения?

Comment: Если я не ошибаюсь, жилетка тут: http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/category/31481-net (я даже открыл один реквест).